# JavaFX smooth scaling

Tags: javafx

I am trying to implement a smooth scaling but setScaleX behaves like "binary" - it jumps (scales) from 1 to x immediately. Is it possible to make a node scale gradually?

For exmple in my FXML file I have a node TableView, FXMLController injects this node

```
@FXML TableView<TableData> tableID;
```

Further I am working with node "tableID" and want it to scale as soon as mouse enters. So my thoughts (code) looks like this:

```
public void doIncreaseTableGradually(){
    for (double i = 0.1; i < 1.5; i = i + 0.1){
    TimeUnit.MILISECONDS.sleep(100);
    doScaleTable(i);
}
}

public void doScaleTable(double i){
    tableID.setScaleX(i);
    tableID.setScaleY(i);
}
```

Quite straightforward. But it turned out that setScaleX does not scale the node as new argument goes in, instead it takes the last value (1.5) and scale it "binary". I tried to find an out-of-the-box class for this like TranslateTransition which translates smoothly but unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: why not use [`ScaleTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/ScaleTransition.html)?

Comment: sounds promising, I will look into it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never sleep the JavaFX application thread - it will just freeze your entire application for the period that the thread is asleep.

Using the [JavaFX animation package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) is the preferred way of performing animations in JavaFX.

Animations work this way:

- The JavaFX system emits a pulse (usually 60 frames a second).
- On each pulse, a callback in the animation system is invoked which interpolates a key property or invokes a key frame event handler to update the attributes of animated node.
- The animated node is rendered with the newly interpolated values.

The process above repeats automatically for each pulse until the animation is complete.  The animation event handlers and interpolation updates occur automatically without application programmer intervention.  So you do not need (and should not) write animation looping and thread pausing logic in your application code.

Here is an example of scaling using the in-built [ScaleTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/ScaleTransition.html) class to perform an animated scale of a node (the example is just a copy and paste from the javadoc):

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
rect.setArcHeight(50);
rect.setArcWidth(50);
rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);

ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000), rect);
st.setByX(1.5f);
st.setByY(1.5f);
st.setCycleCount(4f);
st.setAutoReverse(true);

st.play();
```